# Laravel 5 File Delete Error

Tags: php, mysql, file, laravel-5, delete-file

There is an issue related to my laravel 5 web application regarding the file deletion.

I want to delete an entry from my table with corresponding image file.
Here is my table structure.

```
 Schema::create('master_brands',function($table){
        $table->increments('pk_brand_id');
        $table->string('brand_name');
        $table->string('brand_logo');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I added 3 brands to db and storing image path in **brand_logo** field like : (**/uploads/masters/logocatagory_Computers & IT.png**).

When deleting the record from database I want to delete the image file from uploads folder also.
But the File was not deleting when I performing delete action.
here is my delete controller.

```
  public function branddelete($id)
  {
    $filename = DB::table('master_brands')->where('pk_brand_id', $id)->get();
    $filname =  url()."/app".$filename[0]->brand_logo;
    File::delete($filname); // http://localhost/genie-works/devojp/app//uploads/masters/logocatagory_Computers & IT.png
  }
```

The file is exist in my directory and the directory having 777 permission. !!

I also tried the **Storage** class to delete file.But there is no way !!!..

How can I solve this issue? Any Ideas... :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing it the wrong way. You can't possibly delete a file from URL, you must provide file PATH not URL

Edited

Assuming the file you wish to delete is located in `public/uploads/masters/logocatagory_Computers` you could do this:

```
public function branddelete($id)
{
    $filename = DB::table('master_brands')->where('pk_brand_id', $id)->get();
    $filname =  $filename[0]->brand_logo; 
    //example it.png, which is located in `public/uploads/masters/logocatagory_Computers` folder
    $file_path = app_path("uploads/masters/logocatagory_Computers/{$filname}");

    if(File::exists($file_path)) File::delete($file_path); 
}
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. Simply replace public_path with app_path

Comment: hi dude, can u please share me ur mail id.

Comment: App\Models\File not found exception

Comment: try `use File;` at top of the controller class or try this  `if(\File::exists($file_path)) \File::delete($file_path);`

Answer (score 3):

If you have the file out Storage/app/ , Storage:: does not work, change the /Config/Filesystems.php try put your 'local' at base_path() and comment default storage_path(),

```
    'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => base_path(),
        // 'root'   => storage_path('app'),
    ],
```

Then in Controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

Then in public funtion use Storage Model

```
$path= 'uploads/masters/';
Storage::delete($path . $filname);
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Laravel 5.1.** When using the local driver, note that all file operations are relative to the root directory defined in your configuration file. By default, this value is set to the **storage/app** directory. Therefore,

the following method would store a file in storage/app/file.txt:

```
Storage::put('file.txt', 'Contents');
```

this would delete file.txt in storage/app

```
Storage::delete('file.txt');
```

If you want to change the root directory,take '**storage/app/uploads/**' for example , you could set the filesystem.php as following :

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path('app/uploads/'),
    ],
    ...
```

then this following method would store a file in storage/app/uploads/file.txt:

```
Storage::put('file.txt', 'Contents');
```

this would delete file.txt in storage/app/uploads directory.

```
Storage::delete('file.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that took me quite some time to figure out today:

In case you're trying to delete a list of files that are wrapped in Laravel's own Collection wrapper, you might need to call `->all()` to get the underlying array instance:

```
// The following is an example scenario
$files = Storage::list('downloads');

$collection = collect($files)->filter(function ($file) {
  return str_contains($file, 'temp');
});

Storage::delete($collection->all()); // Note the "all()" call here
```